# Find Regex for states in US having this pattern

Tags: regex

Regex for us state
I want to retrieve state in this string. there is two types.
My string having these types.

US-VA-Arlington
VA-Arlington

In above from these i want to get state(VA) every time.
Please send suggestions.

Thanks,
Girish

Comment: Can the city have spaces in it, like `US-NY-New York`?

Comment: **hai friends what gave answers is use full to me.
But i need another problem in this. please check this link.
In this i want differentiate Location field into three parts.
1. country
2. State
3. City
Please give more suggestions in this.
Thanks**

Comment: What link are we supposed to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following regex

```
([^-]*)-[^-]*$
```

Required state will be captured in `\1`

Comment: Thanks you for the fast reply...it is useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
([A-Z]+)-\w+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regexp:

```
^(?:[A-Z]{2}-)?([A-Z]{2})-
```

The first optional group will match the country code if it exists; but it's a non-capturing group. The second group matches the state code. The state will be in capture group 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
(US\-)?(\w\w)\-(\w+)
```

The first group collects 0 or 1 instances of US-

The second group collects the state abbreviation

The third group collects the city name - you may have to modify this regex to accept spaces (as others pointed out)

Comment: The third group is the city name, not state.